# Javascript Audio doesn't play for first 3 Clicks and plays from 4th click without any issues, what could be wrong?

Tags: javascript

```js
$(".btn").click(function(event){
      playSound(event.target.id);
});

function playSound(name){
  $("." + name).click(function() {
  new Audio("sounds/" + name + ".mp3").play();

});
}
```

Function gets called but audio doesn't play for first 3 or 4 clicks and from 4th or 5th clicks onwards it just works alright, what could be wrong, i tested in Brave and Chrome, same issue in both browsers.

Comment: Instead of this $("." + name). You can use wildcard selector.

Comment: if you are using `id` why you select it as a class with `"." + name`?

Comment: @OmriAttiya `id` is for the name of the file audio files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you **define** the audio play click on the same button instead of playing it.

1. `$(".btn").click` - here you define `onClick` for each element with class `.btn`.
2. You pass to `playSound` the `id` of the clicked button.
3. Now it gets weird: `$("." + name).click` - here you **define** another click event for the class `name` which is the `id` of the clicked button, which makes no sense.

I believe you wanted to play the song when you click the button.

Here's the code that does it:

```js
$(".btn").click(function(event) {
  playSound(event.target.id);
});

function playSound(name) {
  new Audio("sounds/" + name + ".mp3").play();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="btn" id="name1">click to play</button>
<button class="btn" id="name2">click to play</button>
<button class="btn" id="name3">click to play</button>
```

Comment: Yes, removing the additional click solved the issue. Thank You